# Link between eclipse breakpoint and application not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I've been trying to debug a Remote Java Application for about 2 days now without any success on stopping at my breakpoints.
Today talking to a colleague, he noticed that the breakpoints to the UI are not linking to the application.

I've noticed that the breakpoints that are connected to my server, have this sign, showing that they are linked:

[image]

In the meantime, the breakpoints to the UI, don't have this, as seen here:

[image]

Both applications are getting debugged via Remote Java Application. 
Anyone knows why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

For an unknown reason, you'll need to set (perhaps only disable/enable) your breakpoints *after* connecting to the Remote Java Application for them to take effect.

Comment: I tried disabling and enabling them, tried removing and recreating them, tried enabling the "Skip All Braekpoints" and disabling it again, and nothing worked. Still the same problem.

Comment: If it were one breakpoint not working, I would suspect a source mismatch, but it almost sounds like the class files on the server were built with "debugging info" disabled. Check if a method entry breakpoint, set from the Outline, works.